# Using System's AutoCompleteBox in WP

Tags: windows-phone-8, autocomplete, textbox, windows-phone

How can I use autocompletebox of messages' in wp? (Don't want like [this article](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone))

[image: Auto]

Thanks.

Comment: did you read "Don't want like this article" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in your xaml you should declare your TextBox xaml like this:

```
<TextBox InputScope="Chat" />
```

The `InputScope` Property does all the magic you need.